# Como preencher automaticamente o campo de uma tabela com chave estrangeira?

Tags: mysql, python, tkinter

Boa tarde!
Pessoal fiz um formulário onde pego os dados desse formulário e envio para duas tabelas relacionadas. Uma delas é a tabela cadastro (só com informações pessoais) e outra tabela endereço (que recebe apenas o endereço). 
Na tabela cadastro existe um campo Endereço que recebe a forign key (Id_End) da tabela endereço.

Meu problema é: quando preencho o formulário e envio os dados para o banco de dados, todos os campos das tabelas são preenchidos, exceto o campo (Endereço) da tabela cadastro que recebe a foreign key.

Eu gostaria que esse campo fosse preenchido AUTOMATICAMENTE com o (Id_End), que é a chave primária, da tabela endereço. 
Já pesquisei bastante, mas não consegui encontrar uma solução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um print do meu código onde faço a conexão com o banco de dados e envio as informações obtidas pelo formulário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, quando você faz um insert no banco, o banco te retorna alguns dados dessa inserção, um deles é o ID que acabou de ser inserido, assim você pode recuperar o ID que foi inserido na tabela `endereço` e utiliza-lo no insert da tabela `cadastro`, assim:

```
//Primeiro realize o insert na tabela endereço normalmente
CadastroDb.cursor.execut('seu insert da tabela endereço aqui')
CadastroDb.conn.commit()
//agora para pegar o ID que acabou de ser gerado no insert acima
IDEndereco = CadastroDb.cursor.lastrowid
//Aqui coloque o restante das suas variáveis para o insert da tabela cadastro
CadastroDb.cursor.execut('seu insert da tabela cadastro **com o IDEndereco** aqui')
```

Comment: Obrigado, Murilo. Deu certo! Estava travado sem conseguir resolver esse problema. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Abraço.

Comment: @CélioFerreira que bom que deu certo! Se a resposta lhe foi útil considere marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida que você!

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode criar uma variavel para pegar o objeto do endereço que voce quer.
Depois passe esse objeto para o insert no campo foreign key. Um exemplo:

```
endereco = Endereco.objetcts.get(id=1) #Faça a logica para pegar o endereco correto
...
CadastroDB.objects.create(nome=NOME, rg=RG, ..., Id_End=endereco)
```

Não consegui testar aqui. Depois me fala se funcionou

Comment: Boa noite,  Vinicius! Não consegui resolver, acho que não estou sabendo fazer. Sou iniciante e não manjo muito.